# set data-* attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, slim-lang

I have a situation where I need to set dinamically the value for "data-*" on a div. The code I'm using actually is this one:

```
  = tag('div', { class: 'agile-carousel',\
                 data: { carousel_list: url_for(format: :json) } }, true)
  = "</div>".html_safe
```

Which is horrible. Also rails closes the div in a `<div />` fashion, which chrome and other browsers definitely don't like (creating some disasters).

So my solution is that one. I would like to ask if there is another way to do this.

**Update 1:**

Small issue I have, this code:

```
span class==I18n.locale == locale_used ? "inactive" : nil
  = link_to(I18n.t('locale_name', locale: locale_used),\
            url_for(locale: locale_used))
```

If I remove link_to it works. Notice that if I insert even something like `| text` it returns an error: `syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end`

Comment: You should be using `=` instead of `==` unless you explicitly need to output unescaped stuff.

Comment: You should also ask a separate question, as you have an unrelated problem with your updated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `content_tag` instead of `tag` to produce a `<div></div>` instead of a `<div>`, but you shouldn't.

You're using [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/), so *use Slim*:

```slim
.agile-carouesel data-carousel_list=url_for(format: :json)
```

Output:

```
<div class="agile-carouesel" data-carousel_list="some URL"></div>
```

The whole point of Slim and HAML is that you have this fantastically terse syntax for writing tags. You should use it, rather than resorting to Rails' tag helpers when they're not needed. By using them, you're reintroducing all the punctuation clutter that they're supposed to remove.

Comment: I were using slim but I had issue because while the tag helper convers carousel_list to **data-carousel-list**, slim simply returned me an error.

Comment: I just tried it, it doesn't do that. The above outputs `<div class="agile-carouesel" data-carousel_list="whatwhat"></div>` for me, specifically with `data-carousel_list`. It definitely does *not* rewrite your data attributes names, which would render it pretty useless.

Comment: What? There's no missing feature here, it just sounds like you're misusing it. If you use `data-what-ever` or `data-what_ever`, it will output whatever you give it. No part of the `tag` code you posted is something that Slim can't handle.

Comment: I just tested and it works. I'm sorry, I don't understand why previously gave me some troubles when using "-" instead of "_". I'll mark this as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I noticed an important fact, I can't insert any text inside the tag if I use that slim code, read the update in the question.

Comment: The problem is your ternary operator. Use `span class=(I18n.local == ... ? ... : ...)`